# changing page output view after click event on highchart plot point

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have my main page which display multiple graphs and i have the option if the user was to click on a bar or point on a graph it will change the view the page to display relative content on the clicked point.

My problem is that i am not really sure how to properly wire up my content so that i still have my menu bar displayed but my main page content will be switched out with the data of the clicked point.

The click event is through highcharts which is kind of throwing me off on how to properly accomplish this.

This is my main component:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';  

constructor(private myService: MyService, private router: Router) {}

plotOptions: {
                      bar: {
                          dataLabels: {
                              enabled: false
                          }
                      },
                      series: {
                          pointWidth: 15,
                          cursor: 'pointer',
                          point: {
                              events: {
                                  click: function(event: any){
                                     //navigate to another component
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
```

Would i link in my newComponent.ts or newComponent.html? I am not sure what other information is needed to help out but would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you shall use Highcharts `Drilldown` as you're asking something like

> when you click a bar on a barchart, it should break down to its sub bar chart that explains the clicked bar.

[image: DrillDown Stage 1]

[image: Highcharts Drilldown Stage 2]

This image is a snapshot from JSFiddle for explaining the idea

For your reference:

[Highcharts Column with Drilldown](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown)
[Highcharts Map Drilldown](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-drilldown)

Comment: I am looking into your suggestion but i also wanted to know if the drilldown works if i wanted to change the display of the whole page? If i was to click on a bar the page should change then display two different charts.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "display of the page"? any code snippets you have? code of something you're trying...

Comment: You can create chart on drilldown event and place it on the same page. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/801v02gk/. If this is not what you wanted, please let us know.